# How is this effect called (hover 1 item antoherone changes). I don't know how to google it

Tags: hover, effect

i'm sure you can help me.

For example: on [this site](http://brandarena.de/) - when you click on "team" - you can hover over an image and the name is shown on the top. (ja, it's flash, i know ;) )

So, i want to do this in a post-thumbnail-grid in wordpress.

pseudo-code: hover over post-thumbnail(ID) in div1-> show title of post in div2

I don't need a exactly described walk-through.

Just a few keywords, ideas etc.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im guessing even though the example is in flash, you arent wanting a "how to" in flash. What you are looking for is probably **jquery**, if you are looking for what you should be googling, try a jquery hover tutorial or jquery onClick().

try something like this http://bavotasan.com/2009/a-simple-mouseover-hover-effect-with-jquery/ and adapt the hover results to match your criteria.